# MYSQL - Count Query Taking Time

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-attribute-value

I am running the following query and it's taking more than 12 sec on my local system.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    entity_id_0
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        c0_.entity_id AS entity_id_0,
            c0_.sku AS sku_1,
            c0_.visible_in_grid AS visible_in_grid_2,
            c0_.has_options AS has_options_3,
            c0_.required_options AS required_options_4,
            c0_.created_at AS created_at_5,
            c0_.updated_at AS updated_at_6,
            c0_.type_id AS type_id_7,
            c0_.entity_type_id AS entity_type_id_8,
            c0_.attribute_set_id AS attribute_set_id_9
    FROM
        catalog_product_entity c0_
    INNER JOIN catalog_product_website c1_ ON c0_.entity_id = c1_.product_id
        AND (c1_.website_id = 1)
    INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar c2_ ON c0_.entity_id = c2_.entity_id
        AND (c2_.attribute_id = 71)
    WHERE
        (((c2_.value LIKE 'bed%')))
            AND c0_.type_id IN ('base' , 'simple', 'bundle', 'configurable')) dctrn_result
```

If I only run the sub Query it only takes 0.0027 sec

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        c0_.entity_id AS entity_id_0,
            c0_.sku AS sku_1,
            c0_.visible_in_grid AS visible_in_grid_2,
            c0_.has_options AS has_options_3,
            c0_.required_options AS required_options_4,
            c0_.created_at AS created_at_5,
            c0_.updated_at AS updated_at_6,
            c0_.type_id AS type_id_7,
            c0_.entity_type_id AS entity_type_id_8,
            c0_.attribute_set_id AS attribute_set_id_9
    FROM
        catalog_product_entity c0_
    INNER JOIN catalog_product_website c1_ ON c0_.entity_id = c1_.product_id
        AND (c1_.website_id = 1)
    INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar c2_ ON c0_.entity_id = c2_.entity_id
        AND (c2_.attribute_id = 71)
    WHERE
        (((c2_.value LIKE 'bed%')))
            AND c0_.type_id IN ('base' , 'simple', 'bundle', 'configurable')
```

When I tried to understand the query using explain the statement, It shows the following result, and I was not sure how I can improve the performance of the whole query.

[Query with EXPLAIN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5awzZ.png)

Comment: What is the reason to use intermediate subquery which produces multiple-column output?

Comment: Nothing other than c0_.entity_id AS entity_id_0 in the sub query is used so why have the additional columns, which by the way makes the outer query also pointless..

Comment: Why does the title mention count but your query does not?

Comment: I am using doctrine DQL and it automatically creates the subquery and this query is used for calculating the total records for pagination.

Comment: @P.Salmon sorry I forgot to add the count function in the main query.

Comment: @gul - Please add the `COUNT(*)` -- it could drastically change our analysis of your query.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use subquery which selects unneeded columns and results in additional execution step/level.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
        c0_.entity_id AS entity_id_0  
/*                                  ,
            c0_.sku AS sku_1,
            c0_.visible_in_grid AS visible_in_grid_2,
            c0_.has_options AS has_options_3,
            c0_.required_options AS required_options_4,
            c0_.created_at AS created_at_5,
            c0_.updated_at AS updated_at_6,
            c0_.type_id AS type_id_7,
            c0_.entity_type_id AS entity_type_id_8,
            c0_.attribute_set_id AS attribute_set_id_9
*/
    FROM
        catalog_product_entity c0_
    INNER JOIN catalog_product_website c1_ ON c0_.entity_id = c1_.product_id
        AND (c1_.website_id = 1)
    INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar c2_ ON c0_.entity_id = c2_.entity_id
        AND (c2_.attribute_id = 71)
    WHERE
        (((c2_.value LIKE 'bed%')))
            AND c0_.type_id IN ('base' , 'simple', 'bundle', 'configurable')
```

Comment: I tried removing the extra columns but still, there is no difference in execution time.

Comment: @gul *If I only run the sub Query it only takes 0.0027 sec* - does these are your words? Now execute the query from my answer ( !!! add nothing to it !!! ) - does the execution time is the same, ~ 0.0027 sec? Does the output rowset is desired one completely? If so then what else do you need in?

Answer (score 0):

This smells like an EAV schema.  Such designs are notorious for having poor performance when there are lots of rows.

These indexes should help *some*:

```
c2_:  INDEX(attribute_id, value, entity_id)
c0_:  INDEX(entity_type, type_id)
c1_:  INDEX(product_id, website_id)
c1_:  INDEX(website_id, product_id)
```

If value is a `TEXT` column the above index won't be allowed.  See if you can change it to some civilized-size `VARCHAR`.  If you are stuck with `TEXT`, then, try this:

```
c2_:  INDEX(attribute_id, value(20))
```

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the relevant tables; there may be more techniques to help.